Unable to Create SharePoint Webhook Subscription: "AudienceUriValidationFailedException" in Postman
I'm trying to create a webhook subscription for a SharePoint list using the SharePoint API. Following the Microsoft documentation and this guide on using Azure Functions, I am encountering an issue when making a POST request to the /subscriptions endpoint in Postman.
Steps for Obtaining a Delegated Token in Postman:
Authorization Tab:
Auth Type: OAuth 2.0
Auth URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Access Token URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID: Your app's client ID
Client Secret: Your app's client secret
Scope: Sites.ReadWrite.All (or other required scopes)
Grant Type: Authorization Code
Callback URL: Set the redirect URI configured in the Azure portal
Get New Access Token:
Log in with the user account when redirected to the Microsoft login page.
Postman captures the token.
Use the Token:
The token is set in the Authorization header for the request as Bearer {Token}.
Issue:
I'm making a POST request to the SharePoint API using the following payload:
{
  "resource": "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists('{list_id}')",
  "notificationUrl": "https://{your_function_app}.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger?code={code}",
  "expirationDateTime": "2024-12-04T23:59:59.000Z",
  "clientState": "{your_client_state}"
}

However, I receive the following error:
{
  "error_description": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."
}

What I Have Tried:

Verified that the token is correctly generated through the OAuth 2.0 flow.
Ensured that the notificationUrl is accessible and correctly configured.
Checked that the client ID, client secret, and other OAuth 2.0 parameters are correct.
Referenced the Microsoft documentation to confirm the correctness of the API call structure.

What I Am Expecting:
I expect to successfully create a webhook subscription for the SharePoint list without encountering the AudienceUriValidationFailedException error.

If you are using client credential flow to generate access token in app-only scenarios, SharePoint accepts the access tokens requested with only client certificate, but not client secret. Refer MsDoc
If you prefer to use client credential flow and call SharePoint REST API, generate the self-signed in certificate and follow the steps mentioned in GitHub article to generate the access token.
I have followed below steps to create a webhook subscription for a SharePoint list using the SharePoint API.
Created functionapp and generated webhook URL:
https://functionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code={code}


Created AD Application and granted Delegated permission to access sites through SharePoint => Delegated Permissions => AllSites.FullControl

I have used below parameters to generate access token:

Select OAuth 2.0 as Authorization Type.

Grant Type : Authorization Code
Callback URL : Enable Authorize using browser (or) use redirect_uri
Auth URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://{TENANT}.sharepoint.com
Access Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : CLIENTID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope : https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/.default



If you have selected Authorize using browser for Callback URL in postman, add the displayed URL in App=>Authentication=>Redirect URI:


Click on Generate New Access token:

Access token generated as below, click on Use token to be able to run the query to create webhook subscription.

I have used below query to create the subscription using Sharepoint API:
POST https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists('list_id')/subscriptions

Response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xml:base="https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists('list-id')/subscriptions</id>
    <category term="Microsoft.SharePoint.Webhooks.Subscription" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="web/lists('d42361bc-546f-458e-bee6-2a5943d62396')/subscriptions" />
    <title />
    <updated>2024-08-21T12:03:57Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:clientState>secretClientState</d:clientState>
            <d:expirationDateTime m:type="Edm.DateTime">2024-08-22T17:17:57Z</d:expirationDateTime>
            <d:id m:type="Edm.Guid">79691e5f-3XXXX80fb0c3598</d:id>
            <d:notificationUrl>https://kpfunc21.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code={code}</d:notificationUrl>
            <d:resource>d42361bc-XXXXX-458e-bee6-2a5943d62396</d:resource>
            <d:resourceData m:null="true" />
            <d:scenarios m:null="true" />
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>



Thank you for the detailed steps! I'm trying to follow the process to create a webhook subscription using the SharePoint API. Unfortunately, I'm unable to see the images you've provided, which might be crucial for understanding some of the steps. When I reached the last part where the POST request is made to create the subscription, I encountered an issue.

When I executed the POST request, I received the following error:
404 Not Found
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2130575322, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">List does not exist.</m:message>
</m:error>

The error suggests that the list doesn't exist, but I'm sure the list ID is correct. Could there be any additional configurations or steps that I might be missing? Any advice would be appreciated!

First try the GET method to get the lists and check if it works.

Regarding the images, try with some other network and refresh the link.

Thank you for the suggestions! I'm now able to see the images after switching networks.
Regarding the GET method to retrieve the lists, could you please clarify how I can extract the correct list ID? I want to ensure I'm using the correct one.
Also, in the last POST request to create the subscription, could you share the exact body that you sent along with the request? I want to compare it with mine to see if there's any discrepancy.
Thanks again for your help!

My request body: {   "resource": "https://TENANT.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists('list-id')",   "notificationUrl": "https://kpfunc21.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1?code=m46X7rUaXT40Vgoo4cQQl_hLKMv8mDwHTGek5MpXUlOIAzFuN9prRw%3D%3D",   "expirationDateTime": "2024-08-22T17:17:57+00:00",    "clientState": "secretClientState" }

Thank you for sharing the request body. I tried using it with our credentials, but I encountered the same error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2130575322, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">List does not exist.</m:message>
</m:error>


To confirm, I obtained the list ID from the URL that appears when accessing the library settings:
https://{tenant-id}.sharepoint.com/sites/testing/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=%7B{list-id}%7D

Is there a more reliable way to retrieve the correct list ID, or could there be another issue causing this error? Any further guidance would be appreciated!

You can fetch the list id using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SiteID/lists/ in Microsoft Graph Explorer and use that id in your Sharepoint API.

Thank you for suggesting Microsoft Graph to fetch the list ID. I tried using the GET request with the bearer token, but received this error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-08-22T07:16:02",
            "request-id": "-----",
            "client-request-id": "-----"
        }
    }
}

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be appreciated!

Run the query in Graph Explorer | Try Microsoft Graph APIs - Microsoft Graph

I ran the GET request in Graph Explorer and received the following result:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('39159d8e-f64f-44a9-bee7-c4b84')/lists",
    "@microsoft.graph.tips": "Use $select to choose only the properties your app needs, as this can lead to performance improvements. For example: GET sites('<guid>')/lists?$select=displayName,list",
    "value": []
}

It appears no lists were returned for the specified site ID.

However, I do have a list named "Webhook-poc-list" available in my site. I believe there might be an issue with how I'm fetching the list ID or interpreting the data. Could you guide me on how to correctly obtain the list ID or what might be going wrong here? Also, if possible, please help me understand how to create a new list ID for this site. Thank you!

You just have to run the query in Graph Explorer, refer Image.

Refer MSDOC to create the list.

Thank you for the guidance. We successfully retrieved the list ID using the method you suggested. However, when we attempt to create a subscription on our webhook using this list ID, we encounter the following error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <m:code>-2130575322, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code>
    <m:message xml:lang="en-US">List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.
It may have been deleted by another user.</m:message>
</m:error>


We’ve double-checked the list's existence in SharePoint, as shown in the attached image. The list is clearly present, and we're using the correct list ID. Despite this, we're still receiving the error. Could you provide further assistance to help us resolve this issue?
https://imgur.com/a/hQBCgrD
https://imgur.com/a/UP9g02T

Did you grant AllSites.FullControl permission? Also check if the solution provided in SO helps.

Yes, I have granted all the permission as you can see in attached image https://imgur.com/a/kTVmmJE.

Thank you for your continued support. If you need any additional information or details to help troubleshoot this issue further, please let me know. I'm happy to provide anything that might assist in resolving the problem

Did you check the SO link I have shared above?

Yes, We have also checked with this link but didn't find something helpful which can resolve the error.

Please raise a new question with the clear details regarding the error and the steps followed.
